# XML RSS feed JS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rss

My issue is that the code I currently have produces some of the divs, but all the news titles, descriptions and images etc appear in the them divs rather than these pieces of take being in a separate div.

```
$(bbc1).find("item").each(function(){
    var title;
    var desc;
    var tnail;

    title = $(this).find('title').text();
    desc = $(this).find('description').text();
    tnail = $(this).find('thumbnail').last().attr("url");
    $('#thumbHome').append("<div class='col-sm-3' />");
    $('.col-sm-3').append("<div class='thumbnail' />");
    $('.thumbnail').append("<img src='"+ tnail +"'/>");
    $('.thumbnail').append("<div class='caption' />");
    $('$this').append("<h4>" + title + "</h4>");
    $('$this').append("<p>" + desc + "</p>");
    });     
});
```

This is what I have so far, but it currently is not working

Comment: you have a custom dom object named `$this`?

Comment: I think what @madalinivascu is suggesting, is that `$('$this')` should become `$(this)`... Unless you have a custom dom object as suggested...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't get what are you searching for with these lines:

```
title = $(this).find('title').text();
desc = $(this).find('description').text();
tnail = $(this).find('thumbnail').last().attr("url");
```

It tries to find elements: `<title>, <description>, <thumbnail>`. Is this right? Maybe it is ids ("#title") or classes (".title")?